# #FF vs 0xFF numbers conversion

Tags: javascript, html

I get a #FF value from `<input type="color">` 
But for webGL I need a 0xFF value instead. 
I tried `parseInt(num)` and `num.toString(16)` but they had no effect.
Is there a way to cast between them? or maybe tell `<input>` that I want it's value to be saved as 0x values instead?
Short of that, do the different forms of hex have their own names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var v = '#FF';
var dec = parseInt(v.substr(1), 16); // 255
```

`#FF` is not a valid hexadecimal number because of `#`. So you need to trim the leading `#` then perform hex->dec conversion.